# Remove "&nbsp;" using gsub

Tags: r, string, gsub, data-cleaning, string-substitution

I am using this code to remove HTML tags from the data

```
as.data.frame(gsub("<[^>]+>", "", ReflectionData$Answer))
```

But this code does not remove the `"&nbsp;"`.
The data is imported from Excel and the variable answer is a character that contains 12 options. Because of this problem, although options 11 and 14 in the picture are the same they are recognized as different levels of the character.
[image: Options recognized by my later code]

How can I use gsub to get my data completely clean?

Comment: Please edit your question give an example on the data which you would like to clean.

Comment: `rvest`'s `html_text(read_html(ReflectionData$Answer))` will do.